# Cumulative sum value 1 and reset sum when meet 0 SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, cumulative-sum

I am try below  query but it's not working.

```
 SELECT *,
   CASE WHEN x = 1 
   THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date)  
   ELSE 0 END AS y
```

Expected result :

```
  x   y
  1   1
  1   2
  1   3
  0   0
  1   1
  1   2
```

How can I achieve this ? i still want to keep 0 in y column

Comment: what's `date`, I cannot see.

Comment: Hi date and id just dummy for refer but point is compute by column x to new column y :)

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of zeros up to each value and then use this to group.  The final enumeration uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when x = 0 then 0
             else row_number() over (partition by x, grp order by date)
        end) as y
from (select t.*, countif(x = 0) over (order by date) as grp
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thank you i'm very new in sql can you explain Count the number of zeros up to each value? or give me where can i find it :)

Comment: @SitsawekSukorn . . . This is not SQL, it is English, a cumulative sum of the number of rows that have zero values.

Comment: thank you very much i reset to 0 by minus 1 after row number